# "Do nothing" using ternary operator

Tags: java, android

I want to use the ternary operator like this - checking only the `true` part of the statement:

```
foo() ? bar() : /* Do nothing */;
```

Is it possible to exclude the logic of the "else" part of this statement? I tried using `return;` but the compiler gives the error. Basically all I want to achieve is a statement using ternary operator which would look like this:

```
foo() ? bar();
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: Why would you not just use `if`? (No, it's not possible)

Comment: I am just curious if that's even possible. That is all.

Comment: That doesn't actually make any sense.  Expressions must have a value.

Comment: I believe this is actually a desire to have a shorthand for simple if statements, keeping code compact (single line even with IDE formatters, no brackets). Closest semi-valid option is partial short-circuiting with foo() && bar(), since bar() only executes when foo() is true.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The ternary operator is usually used to immediately assign a value.

```
String a = bar() ? foo() : null;
```

For your usecase, you can simply use an if construct:

```
if (foo())
    bar();
```

Comment: Not wrapping the if clause body in braces goes against the good code formatting practices, so this usually becomes 
if (foo()) {
   bar();
} (three lines)

Comment: @IvanMatavulj: that's a matter of taste, and most definitely not a generally accepted best practice. I personally feel brackets are redundant in this case and don't add to readability. I agree with this passionate answer on this topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/16550

Comment: I got an error using `null` I'd rather use `void(0)`

Answer (score 6):

If it would work like that we wouldn't call it ternary anymore.
I think the only way is that do something which does nothing.
for example call a method which has empty body, or if you assign a value from this operation to a variable just assign a default value.